# Removing all duplicates from a generic linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, duplicates

This is the code I've got so far, and it removes all the first instances of the duplicates but if I got an element repeated more than once it will only remove the first instance and leave the rest instances of this element in the list.

```
//remove all duplicate items from list.
// if list is null or empty leave it unchanged

public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
        void deleteReps(LinkedList<T> list)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        T item = list.get(i);
        for(int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++)
        {
            if(item == null && list.get(j) == item || item != null && item.equals(list.get(j)))
            {
                list.remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following Eran's answer, I suggest you should iterate the list with [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) since it eliminate the need for manual indexes and also allows for item removal while iterating the list.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove an element from a list, you have to remember that this will reduce the index for every item after it in the list as well as the size of the list.

EDIT

As sharonbn suggested, here is a working method using an Iterator:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void deleteReps(LinkedList<T> list)
{
    LinkedList<T> noRepsList = new LinkedList<T>();
    Iterator<T> itr = list.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        T currentTest = itr.next();
        if (!noRepsList.contains(currentTest))
            noRepsList.add(currentTest);
        else
            itr.remove();
    }
}
```

This may not be the most effective way to do this as it creates another list to compare objects with but it does get the job done.

Comment: This does work, but as you mentioned the creation of a second LinkedList is horribly inefficient and a waste of memory space, especially when you start to work with doubly LinkedLists

Comment: If you need to stash your unique values somewhere, at least use a `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

With a LinkedList you are dealing with **reference-based** implementation of Objects that are linked together with Nodes. A Node contains an Object and a reference to the next Node only. You should try not to iterate through a LinkedList using indexes because when you start removing or adding Nodes, the indexes change. Unlike an Array that will keep a space null if you remove its content, once you remove a Node from a LinkedList, the list decreases in size, as the previous Node now references the Node that came after the one you deleted, and the deleted Node is lost in memory. So, in your example, you need to take into account that index will change after you remove a duplicate. For this reason, you should always try to traverse a LinkedList in Java via **reference** and not indexing. In your case, this might work:

```
void deleteReps(LinkedList<T> list)
{
    Node prev = head;                         // A node to traverse with starts at the head
    Node temp = head.getNext();               // A second node to traverse with
    Node current = prev;                      // The node in question

    while(prev.getNext() != null)             // While the node after prev isn't the end 
    {                                         //    of the list
        T item = current.data;                // The item we are looking for duplicates of

        while(temp != null)                   // While temp isn't at the end of the list
        {
            if(temp.data == item)             // If the item in temp is the same as the
            {                                 //    item we are looking for

                prev.setNext(temp.getNext()); // Set the next Node of prev to the node
                                              //    after temp. This "deletes" the Node
                                              //    at temp
                prev = temp;                  // prev is now temp
                temp = temp.getNext();        // temp is the next Node
            }
            else                              // Else if the item is different
            {
                prev = temp;                  // prev is now temp
                temp = temp.getNext();        // temp is now the next Node
            }
        } // end while

        current = current.getNext();          // current is now the next Node 
                                              //    so that the
                                              //    the next item we are looking for 
                                              //    duplicates of is an item still in
                                              //    the LinkedList
        prev = current;
        temp = prev.getNext();
    } // end while                               
}
```

I gave thorough comments so you could follow the logic behind this algorithm. This takes into account the shrinking LinkedList as you delete Nodes because `current.getNext()` will always be a Node that is still in the LinkedList after the deletion of duplicates occurs.